# how to transition an older project whose UI is written by code to support Slide Over and Split View of iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

hi，I want to transition an an older project to support Slide Over and Split View of iOS 9，but I find all the demo projects I found was written by storyboard or xib, but my older project's UI is written by code, can any one suggest, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest switching to storyboards to make your life easy.

I would highly recommend you watch the following WWDC videos and then think about what exactly you need to do in order to support multi tasking.

[Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218)

[What's New in Storyboards](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=215)

[Implementing UI Designs in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=407)

[Getting Started with Multitasking on iPad in iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=205)

[Optimizing Your App for Multitasking on iPad in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=212)

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI.
I was not able to adopt Split View until disabled this setting in Project settings->Deployment Info->(Switch iPad)->Status Bar Style->Requires full screen.

Comment: Same worked for me, I deleted the setting in `info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

Just add LaunchScreen storyboard and set it as LaunchScreen from the General settings of your project. You can keep everything else as the code.

Comment: You also need to support all four orientations.